# pass data from javascript to django admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, drop-down-menu, django-admin

I have two dropdown list say, "questions" and "choices" in django admin. Depending on the selected option in "question", options in "choices" will get populated. I wrote a javascript that gets triggered on question change, as shown below. To populate "choices", I need to query the database. Can I do that from this javascript function? If yes, how?

Alternatively, if I could return the selected value to the ModelForm class in django admin, I could query database from there. But I am unable to capture this return value in ModelForm and populate "choices" field after user selects an option in "questions". How do I do that?

I could not find any answer on the internet. All I found was sending data from javascript to django views through HttpResponse. This approach also needs a separate regex definition in urls.py. I cannot change the url while I communicate with javascript.

test.js

```
function tryCustomiseForm() {
    choice=django.jQuery('[id$=choice_list]');
    var selection = null
    django.jQuery('[id$=question_list]').change(function() {
        selection = this.value;
    });
    return selection
}

(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
      tryCustomiseForm();
   });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) to connect my models in models.py.

Answer (score 0):

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452768/how-to-add-ajax-onto-django-admin)

They reccomend: [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/sjrd/django-ajax-selects)

Comment: Possible hacky solution would be to modify (hack) the ModelAdmin to short circuit on a query string or POST and change it's behavior.  IDK why you can't change the urls.py, but that kills a clean solution.